# Are there irreducible cubic surfaces that contain more than 27 lines?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that that a smooth cubic surface contain exactly 27 lines, but are there singular irreducible cubic surfaces which contain more than 27 lines? Or is the number of lines always less than 27?

Comment: Does the "cubic surface" $x^3 = 0$ count, or do you want the surface to be reduced as well?

Comment: Take a smooth plane cubic $C\subset\mathbb P^3$, and now take a point $p\in\mathbb P^3$. The union $S=\bigcup_{q \in C} \overline{pq}$ of the lines connecting $p$ and $C$, a.k.a. the cone over $C$ with vertex $p$, is a cubic surface (since its intersection with a plane is a cubic curve) with a unique singular point at $p$, and lines on $S$ are naturally in bijection with the closed points of $C$. So over an infinite field, $S$ always contains infinitely many lines (uncountably many if the field is).

Comment: Another example is a general projection of a cubic scroll from $\mathbb{P}^4$.